# Force HTTP header

Tags: http, java-me, nokia-s40

The `HttpConnection.setRequestProperty` method allows the setting of HTTP headers.

Some devices like the Nokia 6234 insist on setting their own `User-Agent` causing both headers to appear in the request.

Is there a way to force the header other than implementing HTTP over `SocketConnection`?

If not, is there a way to detect which devices have this problem?